# OpenCart dashboard error - fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: opencart

I have this OpenCart error on the dashboard page below...

```
Warning: fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/download/test) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/var/www/vhosts/Cloud2.chrisames.co.uk/:/tmp/) in 
/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/admin/controller/common/home.php on line 99Warning:
fopen(/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/download/test): failed to open stream:
Operation not permitted in 
/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/admin/controller/common/home.php on line 99Warning:
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/admin/controller/common/home.php on line 
101Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/admin/controller/common/home.php on line 
103Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/download/test) is not within the allowed 
path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/Cloud2.chrisames.co.uk/:/tmp/) in 
/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/admin/controller/common/home.php on line 
105Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in 
/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/admin/controller/common/home.php on line 106
```

any help most appreciated :)

Comment: You have `open_basedir` restriction set on Your server and OpenCart has no **write** acces to this directory `/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/shop/download/`. Either add this path to the `open_basedir` directive or try to set the permission to `775` or `777` (but I guess `chmod` won't work in this case).

Comment: thanks shadyyx, i've got onto my hosting company and they are now fixing this for me:)

Comment: For future reference if you have FTP access you can do this from program's like FileZilla. This will save you a lot of back and forth with your hosting company :) [Filezilla instructions](http://www.cubecartforums.org/docs/appendix/how-to-chmod-directories.html)

Answer (score -2):

Use FileZilla Client (freeware, download and install it https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client or download from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/ )... and then Chmod the directories and the files... 
Set directories 755, files 644. (Servers have their own rules on permissions, but those are nowadays usual.)

That will fix it for you